# css dynamic width of children in a parent container

Tags: php, css

While programming a set of div elements next to each other I encountered a problem. Situation is as follows.

[image]

As you can see in the example image there is an amount of divs being stacked next to each other (the red,green en orange blocks). These live inside a container with a fixed width. Each time the page reloads there are a **different** amount of colored divs. How can i distribute these evenly in the container? (the empty space at the right...)
I though of calculating the width-percentage (i.e. 21.14%) using php and setting it to the elements. This seems to work in Firefox, but it doesn't in IE or safari/chrome. I guess it has something to do with IE and webkit *not being able* to assign a width of i.e. 21.5 px?

Is it possible? And how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
#parentdiv{
    display: table;
}
.childrendiv{//give children divs the same class
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/VdRgn/)

Comment: Okay, that was fairly easy :)
Thanks!